# GA4 data different in date ranges than when adding individual dates up

Tags: google-analytics

Does anyone know a reason why data would be different when selecting say a 2 day date range to adding the data from the 2 days up even though the exploration report says it's unsampled in both and no thresholding is being applied?

For example in sessions if I do it over a date range in an exploration report I get 26,064 sessions, but if I do the dates individually and add the sessions up I get 26,788. Over 700 out, so if expanded over a longer date range this would be way off

Which data should I trust if there's a reason for this?

Screenshots below:

16th Aug (13,814 sessions)
[image]

17th Aug  (12,974 sessions)
[image]

16th-17th Aug (26,064 sessions, but 16th + 17th = 26,788)
[image]

Comment: show some screenshot, pls.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because compared to GA3 where we were used to reading the session data in a summable way, **with GA4 it is not the same**.

GA3 session automatically expires at midnight (11:59:59 pm) and immediately start a new session as soon as the next day begins.

For example, if a user has been browsing your website since 11:50 pm, his session will automatically terminate at 11:59:59 pm even if he continues to engage with your website. At midnight a new GA3 session will start for your user.

Whereas **a GA4 session does NOT automatically expire at midnight** (11:59:59 pm).

So, **the same GA4 session would now be counted twice, once for each day** if you read sessions on a single day, while it recognizes it as a single session if the report includes two days.

For this reason, the total sessions in 2 days may be less than the algebraic sum of the sessions of the individual days.

Comment: thank you for your answer, over longer periods metrics like the transactions & revenue are out when compared to adding individual days